# Given two eigenfunctions and eigenvalues determine existence of eigenvalues between them

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, eigenfunctions

Suppose we have two eigenfunctions $f_n(x,y)$ and $f_m(x,y)$ and corresponding eigenvalues $\lambda_n<\lambda_m$ of a differential operator $L$. How can I determine whether there exists another eigenvalue $\lambda_i$ between these given, i.e. $\lambda_n<\lambda_i<\lambda_m$, if the problem is 2D and higher?

I know that one could just count zeros of the eigenfunctions in 1D case, but according to Courant, Hilbert "Methods of Mathematical Physics Vol. 1", this is not generally true for higher dimensions:

> In the case of eigenvalue problems of partial differential equations, arbitrary values of $n$ may exist for which the nodes of the eigenfunctions $u_n$ subdivide the entire fundamental domain into only two subdomains.

Comment: Do you want to do this numerically/algorithmically or analytically?

Comment: @Sharkos Would be best if analytically, but numeric solution is fine too